# delete export record from which table?

Tags: database, export, importexport

for some reason, I have to delete this record from the table, (it is stuck, cannot download or delete)
anyone know this record belongs to which table? so I can delete it by sql query
[image: m]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is a folder created at /var/export/email

after delete and it will gone

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not save any database table but you remove the   .csv file in automatically generated `/var/export/your .csv`.

And backup the csv file and after you want to delete.

May be help you..

Helpful this answer so accept..